# AWS paperclip rails AllAccessDisabled Error on image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, devise, paperclip

I get this error when attempting to upload an image via the paperclip gem and store the images in an AWS bucket on signup.  I get this error after entering my access key id and secret access key into the aws.rb initializer to test locally  What could this error mean?

```
AWS::S3::Errors::AllAccessDisabled in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
All access to this object has been disabled
```

Comment: Make sure your bucket name is correct.

Comment: AWS.config(
s3_bucket_name: 'xxx',
access_key_id: 'yyy',
secret_access_key: 'zzz')   I have here my bucket, access key id, and secret key set and my bucket matches the one I created.  When I change the access/secret key to be wrong I get an Invalidkey error.  But when they are correct I get the AllAccessDisabled error.  Seems like it is reaching my bucket but some permission could be missing?

Comment: But I went into the permissions of my bucket and granted to everyone and checked upload/delete, edit, view permissions, and list.  I added a policy aswell bc I heard that could help.   {
 "Id": "Policy1453759446098",
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "Stmt1453759420276",
   "Action": [
    "s3:GetObject"
   ],
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tumblitter2/*",
   "Principal": "*"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: How you are uploading file to s3 ? Might be this answer could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655936/aws-sdk-v2-allaccessdisabled-error-for-s3-file-copy